# How can I label / mark text in local website for machine learning issues

Tags: javascript, html

I want to inject javascript in a local website that I can click with my mouse for example to all footer texts to mark (Label) this DOM element somehow for later content extraction with machine learning.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a class:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.target.setAttribute("class", "marked");
});
```

```css
.marked {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <p>Something's wrong with me. Click me to "mark" me.</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: OP want to later extract marked elements. Can you target elements by css?

Comment: @Andrew1325 I don't understand, what do you mean "target elements by css"?

Comment: With my mouse click I want to decide which text is marked. For example if I click on the word „contact“ then for example in html source code a new class should be added around (!) the word , like this: <div class=„my_just_added_label>contact</div>